# how to add phonegap framework 2.9 into xcode 6

Tags: cordova

I want install phonegap framework into xcode, that can make me new phonegap project as easy as new singleView empty project. please tell me.[image]

Comment: wait a minute, xcode 6.3 ?

Answer (score -1):

you can use terminal to create a sample project

```
cd phonegap-2.9.0/lib/ios/bin
./create test test test
```

or as document: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_command-line_index.md.html

```
$ ./path/to/cordova-ios/bin/create /path/to/my_new_cordova_project com.example.cordova_project_name CordovaProjectName
```

start your project with that sample, since version 2.0 there is no .dmg file or installer for Cordova/Phonegap project in xcode

for more infomation, try `./create --help` to know more detail about parameter in create command

---

Comment: I know this way, but i feel it very troublesome

Comment: okay, if you can not find another solution, just try one, use my sample. it's easy. good luck.